# How to download a pdf from an Android Webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an application that launches a `webivew`. When I click on the `PDF` links in the `webview`, download of that `PDF` should start. I am able to do this with the following code.

```
view.getContext().startActivity(
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
```

Here the moment the download starts my current `webview activity` is closed, as I give `startActivity()`.

But I want user to be on the `webview` itself and download should start in the background without vanishing the `webview`. What is the way around for that? Kindly help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do one thing. The moment the PDF download starts, then see to it that your webview activity is prevented from onDestroy() or finish().

Then u can start the download in background and also retain the Webview activity.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried on the similar lines and it worked. Thanks again!!!!